# Why does my calculator automatically open (multiple times) when my computer is idle?

Tags: calculator

Calculator is opening multiple times automatically during normal operation and while idle.

Comment: Do you have a cron job set up?

Answer (score 5):

Worth a shot:

Many keyboards have a key to open the calculator, perhaps yours is stuck.

To check if this is happening, go to *System → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts* and look for "Launch Calculator". The assigned key should be `XF86Calculator`.

Set a new shortcut, one that you're not going to trigger by accident, and see if it's still happening.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, try disable it..

Answer (score 0):

It might be short circuit issue.I had same issue where my calculator opened automatically and at same point of time character from keyboard got pressed multiple times

e.g when i pressed q it printed qqq  and so on

i had my CPU on computer table but when i kept on floor then problem got resolved. I think my home electric supply is not grounded so it happened but ultimately after 5 hours of hit and trail method i resolved my issue.